# LaTeX pdf screen not appearing and pdf file not compiling after removing /usr/local

Tags: compiling

I'm running on macOS Big Sur 11.4.

Recently, I wasn't able to compile R packages properly, so it was suggested to me to remove all file from /usr/local via

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/*
```

Now my packages compile as needed, but for some odd reason, LaTeX pdfs no longer compile.

When I navigate over to `/usr/local/bin` and look at what files are there, I see

```
R           makeinfo        texi2any
Rscript         pdftexi2dvi     texi2dvi
gfortran        pod2texi        texi2pdf
info            sqlite3_analyzer    texindex
install-info        tclsh8.6        wish8.6
```

but I'm not sure if something may have been erased.

I'm no computer wizard, so any help in fixing the issue is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

When I do a Quick Build, the pdf screen does not appear and the pdf is not generated. I just get a number of warnings pertaining to missing fonts and under/overfulls, which were not there prior to the problem occurring. The square boxes in the blue text were there before the problem happened when I updated to macOS Big Sur

[image]

Comment: Whoever made that suggestion was wrong. They had no idea what was under `/usr/local`. If it is failing to compile, you need to update your question with the details of the failure.

Comment: I have added more details. Hopefully someone can help.